# Rails and spreadsheet import/export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spreadsheet

What's a best-in-class Rails option for importing/exporting spreadsheet data? Preferably w/o requiring an intermediate conversion to/from .CSV?

I see several options, but no clear preference (thus far). Ideas?

Thanks & regards,
Brian Piercy

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just export csv?

Comment: This is mostly an import question. Most users will be Excel jockeys; an intermediate step is an inconvenience.

Answer (score 4):

Have you seen http://spreadsheet.rubyforge.org/ ?